# Multiple WP_Query loops with Pagination

Tags: wp-query, pagination, loop

There are a few other questions about this (and WP_Query pagination seems to be a huge question for a lot of people) so I'm trying to narrow down exactly how to make it function.

I'm able to create a single custom loop with pagination this code:

```
// http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$args = array(
    'showposts' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$wp_query->query($args);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

// The Post
the_title();
echo '<br>';
the_category(' ');
the_excerpt();
echo '<hr>';

endwhile;
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links#Examples
$big = 999999999;
$pag_args = array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
);
echo paginate_links($pag_args);
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
```

...but naturally if I copy/paste this loop, it works as an exact clone, meaning, when you click on "Page 2" it takes you to Page 2 for BOTH the loops.

Is there a way to break these apart from each other so each paginates separately?

Here's the full code complete with duplicate loop if anyone is interested in setting up their own local version and toying with it: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/573108/

Comment: look at this post which I have solved multiple loop pagination problem for myself http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126814/wordpress-static-page-pagination/139594#139594

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. The key is to make the `format` parameter different for the two queries:

```
    <!-- Cats -->
    <div class="animals">
        <?
            $paged1 = isset( $_GET['paged1'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged1'] : 1;
            $paged2 = isset( $_GET['paged2'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged2'] : 1;

            // Custom Loop with Pagination 1
            // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage
            $args1 = array(
                'paged'          => $paged1,
                'posts_per_page' => 2,
            );
            $query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );

            while ( $query1->have_posts() ) : $query1->the_post();
                the_title();
                echo '<br>';
                the_category(' ');
                the_excerpt();
                echo '<hr>';
            endwhile;

            // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters
            $pag_args1 = array(
                'format'  => '?paged1=%#%',
                'current' => $paged1,
                'total'   => $query1->max_num_pages,
                'add_args' => array( 'paged2' => $paged2 )
            );
            echo paginate_links( $pag_args1 );
        ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Dogs -->
    <div class="animals">
        <?
            // Custom Loop with Pagination 2
            $args2 = array(
                'paged'          => $paged2,
                'posts_per_page' => 2,
            );
            $query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

            while ( $query2->have_posts() ) : $query2->the_post();
                the_title();
                echo '<br>';
                the_category(' ');
                the_excerpt();
                echo '<hr>';
            endwhile;

            $pag_args2 = array(
                'format'  => '?paged2=%#%',
                'current' => $paged2,
                'total'   => $query2->max_num_pages,
                'add_args' => array( 'paged1' => $paged1 )
            );
            echo paginate_links( $pag_args2 );
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying Boone. I see what you're saying, but whenever I try to change the get_query_var, it throws an error.

Here's the updated code: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/573208/

The error:

    Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\wordpress_wp_query_pagination\wp-includes\query.php on line 27

Comment: Two things: 1) You are doing some odd things with the `$wp_query` global. (2) There are some implementation oddities in `WP_Query` itself that make it impossible to use `get_query_var()` and some other functions with it, so I generally reference the `$_GET` superglobal directly, making sure to sanitize by casting to `int`. I've updated my answer with a full working example.

Comment: Awesome Boone! Thanks so much, works great. Time to study it thoroughly.

The weird WP_Query stuff was from this 2008 article: http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/

I figured maybe the get_query_var was fetching the same var, but didn't have the brain to get it directly with $_GET.

Again, thanks a lot man. Been fighting with this forever.

Comment: Cool. Good luck!

Comment: Ah crap. Care to keep fighting this with me? :)

After testing your version I noticed it doesn't go back to page 1. It gets stuck on page 2.

Also, when you click on a different page, it resets the other loop. Is it possible to chain these $_GET variables together so it remembers http://foo.com/?paged_1=2&paged_2=3 ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "gets stuck". As for the other point - yes, that's what I meant by the last sentence in my answer. You'll have to concatenate the `'base'` or `'format'` params so that they are aware of the other pagination argument.

Comment: Here's the bug I'm getting: http://www.screenr.com/tmS8
Here's my code (same bug with your verbatim code): http://paste.pocoo.org/show/573351/

Comment: OK, I changed the answer again.

Comment: Seems to work perfect. Thank you sooo much Boone! You're an Ivy League genius. :D

Out of curiosity, how does that 'add_args' parameter work exactly? I looked at the Codex but it's not very specific.

Comment: `add_args` lets you add an array of arguments to the URL. It's clearer in the inline docs and in the function itself: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1876 https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1985

Comment: can u have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841520/pagination-error-wordpress

Comment: I know this is old but it's working for me. Question, how would I do re-write rules for this?