# Pagination error Wordpress multiple loop

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I have multiple loops using `wp_query()` in WordPress. I want to show the posts from first loop first (post per page=10), and if there are no posts from first loop show, then show the second loop.

For example, if I only have 8 posts from first loop, the second loop should show 2 posts.

The loop is working properly, but I can't solve the post per page issue. How can I do this? I also need pagination for the remaining posts.

```
$args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'event',
                'event-categories'  => 'featured',
                'orderby'           =>  'meta_value_num', 
                'order'             =>  'ASC',

        );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$args1 = array(
            'post_type'         => 'event',
            'event-categories'  => 'abc'
            'orderby'            =>  'meta_value_num', 
             'order'             =>  'ASC',

        );

$loop1 = new WP_Query( $args1);
```

Comment: You say you want to show the second loop if there are no posts in the first; but then, in your example, you have a loop with 8 posts, and you want to show the second with 2 posts. This seems contradictory. Do you mean "if there are less than 10 posts in the first loop, show post from the second loop, up to a maximum of 10 posts in total (loop 1 + loop 2)", i.e. if loop 1 = 3, then loop 2 = 7, if loop 1 = 1, then loop 2 = 9, etc.?

Comment: i mean if there is no enough posts to full the page, ie; i need 10 posts in a page.   u r correct.

Comment: So:
posts_per_page (loop 2) = 10 minus posts_per_page (loop 1)?
I don't have time right now to submit a full answer, but I would start by using `get_query_var` to find the number of posts returned for each loop and then doing a calculation to find the correct value for loop 2 `posts_per_page`.

Comment: (y) how can i do that

Comment: You could maybe adapt the answer to this question to get the post count http://wordpress.org/support/topic/displaying-a-div-after-a-post-while-changing-position-based-on-number-of-posts

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<?php

    //Protect against arbitrary paged values
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'category_name' => 'case-study',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'show_all'     => False,
        'prev_next'    => True

    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>


<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

//Insert your data feed here - links / images / text etc etc

 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Pagination code below:

```
<?php

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'prev_next' => 'true',
        'type' => 'list',
        'link_before' => '',
        'link_after'  => '',
        'prev_text'    => __('< FIRST'),
        'next_text'    => __('LAST >'),
        'show_all' => 'true',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
    ) );

 ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i have two loops. hope u hav read question carefully

Comment: Hey yes I understand that. You can place your ARGS when mine are and it should be fine. Try it out and let me know how you get on :)

Comment: @NishamMahsin do you need to remove duplicate posts from the second loop?

Comment: i have done that. but that is not my proble. i hop u understood.thnx for help

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47259/multiple-wp-query-loops-with-pagination   i have done pagination like this. but only second loop is changing

Comment: Post all of your code please and I will take a look!